# Finding objectForKey in search results

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a list of NSMutableArrays with `NSMutableDictionaries` in with objectsandkeys in this. like:

```
    [silestoneArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                           initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Zen: Unsui", @"name",
                           @"silestone-unsui1.jpg", @"image", nil]];
```

I have a working search but I am now trying to segue to a detail view. I need to find a way of calling up the objects and keys from the search results so that when I segue from the search results the correct data is passed on.

My didselectrowatindexpath and prepareforsegue look like this:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == self.mainTableView){

        [self.detailViewController setDetailItem:[[contentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]
                                                  objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];}
    else
        [self.detailViewController setDetailItem:[[contentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]
                                                  objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];
}

#pragma mark - Segue


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailview"]) {
        UIViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        // In order to manipulate the destination view controller, another check on which table (search or normal) is displayed is needed
        if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            detailViewController = self.detailViewController=segue.destinationViewController;
        }
        else {NSLog(@"Sender: %@", [sender class]);
            self.detailViewController=segue.destinationViewController;
        }
    }
}
```

and this passes to a detailview which call forth the data like so:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.navigationItem.title = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"name"];
        [self.detailImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.detailItem[@"image"]]];
    }
}
```

The problem I have at the moment is when I segue from the results it will send the results from my original table so no matter what the cell of the results says the image and title will correspond with the order of the unfiltered results.

I know this is because I am calling on contentsList for both in didselectrow but when I try with search results it crashes.

the error report is: `-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21ed8`

and under exemption breakpoints it says it is being thrown at this point:

```
        self.navigationItem.title = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"name"];
```

in this section of the detail view:

```
    - (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.navigationItem.title = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"name"];
        [self.detailImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.detailItem[@"image"]]];
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the crash info. This only happens when I change the didselectrowatindexpath to '- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == self.mainTableView){
        
        [self.detailViewController setDetailItem:[[contentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]
                                                  objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];}
    else
        [self.detailViewController setDetailItem:[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}'

Comment: contentsList is the NSMutableArray that contains all of my data. I have 4 arrays which are like the example above holding all of the dictionaries and then these are then contained in ContentsList like so:     NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:graniteArray,marbleArray,quartzArray,silestoneArray, nil];
    [self setContentsList:array];

Comment: Please NSLog your contentsList and tell me what is on the console ?

Comment: I'm new to NSLogging, what would you like me to put where?

Comment: please put `NSLog(@"Array Content : %@",contentsList);` as the first line of didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: It says: Array Content : (
        (
                {
            image = "angel-cream.jpg";
            name = "Angel Cream";
        },
and so on through all my data

Comment: Basically contentsList is calling up all of the keys but the search results only have the titles and no keys at all. Is there any way I can get them to include the keys as well?

Comment: @David: just use like: [self.detailViewController setDetailItem:[contentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: I should have said that the segue from the original table view works perfectly it's just the search results that don't. Also is there anyway to change the look of the search display controller to match that of the original table view?

Comment: [self.detailViewController setDetailItem:[contentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; has the same error as before